# Removing google analytics from a google site copy

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

We have a live google classics site that is currently tracked in google analytics. Because there is still work to be done, the team created a copy of our site for internal use, and it seems to be separate from the live site. The copied site isn't just a copied page or template. It's its own entity.

The problem is that Google Analytics combines both sites' data, so the overview data is not representative of the actual usage. I have 2 assumptions.

1. When the copy was made, it copied all settings including enabling analytics and the Analytics Web Property ID.
2. Or, someone enabled Analytics for the copy and added the same Analytics Web Property ID

All of this happened before my time, and since I am not an owner, I can't see the settings in 'Manage Site'. To my knowledge though, all the owner has to do is go to Settings -> Manage Site -> Statistics -> No Analytics for the copy site only. My fear is that in doing so, it affects the live copy as well and we disable the Analytics. But that wouldn't make sense considering they are 2 separate sites.

A side question is, when we disable Analytics, does the data already collected disappear, or if we reenable with the same tracking, then the data comes back?

So my question is, how do we get Analytics to stop combining the 2 sites' data? (Disable Analytics and remove the Analytics Web Property ID of the copy?)

Thank you so much!
Teresa

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the analytics data, you can probably filter it by "hostname".

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en

What you would do in this case, you'd create a exclude filter, put in the hostname of the domain that you don't want and the view will prevent data coming in if it has that hostname.

The data won't disappear for the past and will reappear if you remove the filter, but the data for during the time when the filter is active won't be there. Essentially the data won't be collected.